# Magento Connect Going to Error Page 404

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I am trying to install an  extension on the store but when i visit the Magento Connect from admin panel its going to and Error page how to fix it.
I have tried by setting permission to download folder 755 and index.php t0 664 but still the error present.

FILE PERMISSION:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chmod o+w var app/etc
sudo chmod 550 mage 
sudo chmod -R o+w media
```

And if i delete my htaccess file then Magento connect works fine but the store stopped working in this case

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like your `.htaccess` file is blocking something. Replace that file from default installation of magento. If you want to know the issue please post your `.htaccess` code here.